# JavaFX don't send me to next scene

Tags: javafx

I want to move to next stage after Timer but when I run the page is frozen.

I want some help please to resolve this problem, I'm new in JavaFX .

I want to go to next screen after a specific time that I choose because this screen is a load screen

this is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chapitreapp;

import ressources.FadeInLeftTransition;
import ressources.FadeInRightTransition;
import ressources.FadeInTransition;
import ressources.config;
import ressources.config2;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import org.springframework.beans.*;
import org.springframework.context.*;


/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author anas
 */
public class LoadController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Text lblWelcome;
    @FXML
    private Text lblRudy;
    @FXML
    private VBox vboxBottom;
    @FXML
    private Label lblClose;
    Stage stage;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imgLoading;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        longStart();
        lblClose.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });
        // TODO

    }   

    private void longStart() {
        Service<ApplicationContext> service = new Service<ApplicationContext>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<ApplicationContext> createTask() {
                return new Task<ApplicationContext>() {           
                    @Override
                    protected ApplicationContext call() throws Exception {
                        ApplicationContext appContex = config.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
                        int max = appContex.getBeanDefinitionCount();
                        updateProgress(0, max);
                        for (int k = 0; k < max; k++) {
                          try
                          {
                                Thread.sleep(50);
                             updateProgress(k+1, max);

                           }
                           catch(InterruptedException e)
                           {
                                    System.exit(0);
                           }
                        }
                        return appContex;
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        service.start();
        service.setOnRunning((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            new FadeInLeftTransition(lblWelcome).play();
            new FadeInRightTransition(lblRudy).play();
            new FadeInTransition(vboxBottom).play();
        });
        service.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {

            config2 config = new config2();
            config.newStage(stage, lblClose, "/chapitreapp/FXMLDocument.fxml", "Sample Apps", true, StageStyle.UNDECORATED, false);
        });
    } 
}
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is unclear from your code where it's going wrong. You should create a new Scene from your fxml document and set the new Scene on the Stage when you fire the event. Not sure what ressources.config2 is and what it's doing in its newStage method. You don't really need a new Stage. You need a new Scene which needs to be set on the existing Stage. Or you keep the existing Scene and just change its root Parent element to be the new Parent from the loading of the fxml document. Either is fine.

Comment: Can you help me with just a code that take to next scene after a specific time? so in     `private void longStart() {
                        new FadeInLeftTransition(lblWelcome).play();
            new FadeInRightTransition(lblRudy).play();
            new FadeInTransition(vboxBottom).play();
     //here to spend to next scene after a time  
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, in your onSucceeded event handler, or a method that it calls...

```
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("nextScene.fxml");
        if (url != null) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            Parent root = loader.load(url);
            Scene newScene = new Scene(root);
            this.getStage().setScene(newScene);
        } else {
            System.out.println("URL was null");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

In your controller, you will need to have some means of setting the stage, either via a constructor that accepts the Stage object or via a setStage() method. I've used a getStage() method above to access the Stage and set the new Scene object on it.

You could also use the static FXMLLoader load method: `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);`

This may also be of benefit: https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1